# Ubuntu 18.04 shows this error message (ACPI BIOS error) and hangs

Tags: boot, 18.04

This is what happened: I started Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) and it froze for a couple of minutes at the Ubuntu logo. My laptop usually takes less than a minute to start. Then I held the power button for 10-20 secs to forcibly turn off the machine. Then I started the machine again. This time no Ubuntu logo came up. Instead, it gave the following error message:

[image]

```
03/psobject-221) 
[   0.337014] ACPI BIOS error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.XMC.RHUB.SS10._UPC].AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-324)
[   0.337014] ACPI Error AE_AlREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221) 
[   0.337014] ACPI BIOS error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.XMC.RHUB.SS10._UPC].AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-324)
[   0.337014] ACPI Error AE_AlREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221) 
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 382298/1831424 files, 6267162/7324160 blocks
[   3.024318] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: pciehp: failed to check link status
```

I haven't tried to start the laptop after that. Any ideas what the error means and what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here are tips for linux:

Do not force close linux by powering off.

Even if you think Ubuntu is frozen you need to wait, specially when booting.

There is nothing you can do right now but to turn on the laptop and wait as long as it takes untill the Ubuntu either starts or give you more errors and restart itself. Unless you want to reinstall it which will be even worse.